# Prime properties

Tags: prime-numbers

Are there any properties that all primes share in common (while all the non-primes don't share it), and could be written in a simple formula which involves only 1 positive integer variable? 
Thank you!

Comment: $n$ is prime iff $n>1$ and for all natural numbers $k$ holds that if $k$ divides $n$ then $k= 1$ or $k= n$.

Comment: no that was not what I was looking for, that is a definition of a prime number, still thank you

Comment: my comment was meant to force a more precise question. I did post a more serious answer though.

Answer (score 6):

[Wilson's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem): $n$ is prime iff $n>1$ and $(n-1)!=-1$ modulo $n$.

Comment: Thank you. I got the same result although written a bit different:
n is prime iff e^(24*PI*( (2n choose n)-1)/n^3  )=1
This was actually the reason I was asking the question.

Comment: just to show everyone what I initially thought was going on afterwards
e^(i*24*PI*( (2n choose n)-1)/n^3 )*cos^2(PI*n)-1=0 holds for all real numbers >0 from there it's almost no problem to catch the nullpoints.